# Rails: Production Rails console won't start

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Everything works fine on my OS X development laptop.

Deploy the app to production and it runs and displays data as expected.

However, when I try to run the Rails **console** on the production server I get an error...

```
$ rails console -e production
/opt/deployed_rails_apps/con_app_rails_3/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:
    in `connect': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
        '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)

    from /opt/deployed_rails_apps/con_app_rails_3/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
    from /opt/deployed_rails_apps/con_app_rails_3/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
```

I tried removing `socket: /tmp/mysql.sock` from database.yml -- same result.

Although the app runs, I do need to be able to access the console in production as well to perform certain tasks.

I am able to connect to the MySQL server using the MySQL command line client.

---

ruby 1.9.3p125

Rails 3.2.2

mysql2 gem 0.3.11

MySQL server:  5.1.61

Production host: Linux 2.6.32-220.4.2.el6.x86_64

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: con_app_rails_3_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: con_app_rails_3_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  host: dbhost
  database: con_app_rails_3_production
  pool: 5
  username: xxxx
  password: xxxx
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Solved it.

All I needed to do was...

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

Comment: I didn't need to do `bundle exec`, but specifying `RAILS_ENV=production` FIRST on the command line was important.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to do this:

`./script/rails console production`

Answer (score 1):

I solved with run:

```
 RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c
```

more details on [link](http://akbarbin.blogspot.com/2013/05/rails-console-on-staging-or-production.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this by appending the `--environment=production` argument to the `rails c` or `rails console` command

```
rails c --environment=production
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**