# Cannot start rails console in production: invalid option -e

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, console, rails-console

For some reason, we cannot run rails console in production. The command `rails console -e production` works on our Windows machine but fails on our Mac.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440553/production-rails-console-wont-start) explains how to solve it, but can someone explain why we're seeing this error message on one machine and not the other?

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:23:in `block in start': invalid option: -e (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:18:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:18:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try just `rails console production` or `RAILS_ENV=production rails console`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says, `-e` is not a valid option for a rails console command (in your version of Rails). This is the proper usage:

```
$ rails console --help
Usage: console [environment] [options]
    -s, --sandbox                    Rollback database modifications on exit.
        --debugger                   Enable ruby-debugging for the console.
        --irb                        DEPRECATED: Invoke `/your/choice/of/ruby script/rails console` instead
```

Comment: funnily enough, I see the `-e` switch.. details in my answer. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I do see the -e option. Funny

```
rails console --help
```

gives

```
Usage: rails console [environment] [options]
    -s, --sandbox                    Rollback database modifications on exit.
    -e, --environment=name           Specifies the environment to run this console under (test/development/production).
                                     Default: development
        --debugger                   Enable the debugger.

rails console -e production
```

gives me

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.0.1)
irb(main):001:0>
```

I am on Rails 4.0.1.

**Edit** - missed the part about the problem being in 3.2.12.

Comment: The question is about 3.2.12 though.